# FileChannel map - Cannot extend for writing

Tags: java, nio, filechannel

I'm opening large file (~ 200 MB) with RandomAccessFile and then get Channel for it. I'm trying to map some data to MappedByteBuffer, but I'm getting exception:

> Channel not open for writing - cannot extend file for required size.

I can't figure out, why map method tries to write to the file - mapping area is smaller than file size! Why it's trying to extend file in this case?

**Update**

Problem solved, it turned out that I thought that 3rd parameter indicated for index position in file, that it was the length of the buffer.

Comment: @EJP : Ok, formatted. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doc:

> Parameters:
>
> **position** The position within the file at which the mapped region is to start; must be non-negative
>
> **size** The size of the region to be mapped; must be non-negative and no greater than java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE

What exactly the file size you have?
Are you trying to map offset+size that exceeds the file size?

Comment: Yea.. thanks! I've read somewhere, that map accepts index of sector end, not size of it. my bad.